# falcon framework

Tags: python, flask

Ребят начал изучать **Falcon**, но при запуске страници возникла проблема,подскажите пожалуйста  что я делаю не так!

**Логи:**

```
(venv) user@hameleon:~/lessons/api$ http localhost:8000/quote        
http: error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /quote (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)) while doing GET request to URL: http://localhost:8000/quote
```

**Код:**

```
    import falcon


    class QuoteResource:
        def on_get(self, req, resp):
            """Handles GET requests"""
            resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
            resp.body = ('I\'ve always been more interested in the future than in the past.')

    app = api = falcon.API()

    quotes = QuoteResource()

    api.add_route('/quote', quotes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что сервер, то есть скрипт с кодом из листинга, не запущен.
Сначала нужно запустить сервер

```
(venv) user@hameleon:~/lessons/api$ python app.py
```

А уже потом подключаться клиентом `http` или из браузера заходить

```
user@hameleon:~/lessons/api$ http localhost:8000/quote
```

Comment: Будем пробовать,спасибо